# Бинарное дерево или сортировка? C++

Tags: c++

Я бы хотел узнать, что будет быстрее:

- Сортировать(quick sort) массив и выводить его.
- Сразу записывать все в бинарное дерево и потом выводить его.

Проблема в том, что я принимаю файлы с числами типа double, и мне надо их записывать отсортированными уже в другой файл и надо делать это быстро. Файлы имеют минимальный размер 1ГБ.
Использую язык C++.
Также надо учитывать наихудшие варианты.

Comment: в вашем случае будет разумно использовать именно бинарное дерево, так как оно будет сортировать прямо во время записи. Если сначала записывать в массив, а потом сортировать, то, ИМХО, будет больший расход времени.

Comment: Массив, вероятно, быстрее - просто потому что память можно выделить сразу, файлы читать блоками, прямо в память, не нужны постоянные выделения памяти (а гасят производительность они страшно). Но, по-хорошему, надо просто написать оба варианта и замерить - это единственный надежный путь. Кстати, дерево вы планируете реализовывать сами или просто взять `set`?

Comment: быстрота зависить будет от количества элементов и от того, в кком порядке находятся  элементы в файле. Есть ситуации, когда  O(n) быстрее  O(logn)

Comment: Дерево я буду реализовывать буду сам

Comment: С точки зрения конечного машинного кода, массив конечно быстрее, но сортировка.. может убить все преимущества.. причём, если контролировать дубли значений, надо сортировать массив после каждого добавления (qsort) и проверять предварительно, есть ли оно там (bsearch). Или писать этот функционал самому, но надо помнить, что там SSE оптимизация уже включена, в дефаулт функциях.

Comment: Тут два варианта (дерево или массив), можно же просто протестировать и выяснить что будет быстрее. Или даже реализовать оба метода и выбирать наиболее подходящий в зависимости от внешних условий.

Comment: А памяти у вас сколько доступно? Если хватает, то qsort. Если нет, то внешняя сортировка. Сортируете qsort по частям и записываете в файлы. Потом многопутевое слияние в результирующий файл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Быстрее будет сортировка в массиве. Меньше промахов в кэше, меньше расход памяти, да и быстрая сортировка STL работает очень хорошо. Миллионы чисел сортируются за секунды.

Если у вас есть возможность узнать, сколько элементов хранится в памяти, то могу посоветовать заранее выделить необходимо количество памяти в массиве. В случае использования **std::vector**, это будет функция **reserve** или сразу передать в конструктор необходимое количество элементов.

Что касается считывания, то стоит помнить, что данные все равно подгружаются из буфера (т.е. из файла загружается какая-то часть в буфер, например, 4КБ, а потом читается с буфера, когда вы используете считывание), поэтому происходит считывание достаточно быстро.

И ещё одна вещь, которая может сэкономить вам память и увеличить скорость. Это если в файле они хранятся в бинарном виде, а не в текстовом. Это также позволит узнать, сколько чисел хранится в файле и потом выделить память.

Answer (score 1):

Динамическое бинарное дерево займёт в памяти огромное количество памяти для ссылок (три штуки) и баланс. Миллиардные попытки выделить память для каждого узла займёт времени на всю область вашего терпения. Можно конечно первым проходом посчитать количество данных в файле и выделить одноразово память для массива узлов деревьев. Но намного проще выделить память в три раза меньше для обычного массива данных и произвести быструю сортировку. Результат: подсчёт количества данных, запись в обычный массив, quick-sort.